# Set Timespan for a AppInsight RestAPI Context

Tags: azure-application-insights

When calling application rest api from powerbi or a console app how could I set the timestamp, example 30 days ago etc. You could put that inside the code but then it is hard to resue across different environment example powerbi, appinsight console, or putting the query to the azure Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/appId/query?**timespan=P30**

The above will get 30 days of data if you want 7 days just set timespan to P7

For custom timerange do following
Request URL: https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/apId/query?timespan=2019-06-05T01:03:54.586Z/2019-06-12T01:03:54.586Z